# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed when loading into browser

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project in visual studio that imports a CSV, and exports an XML file. I'd like to be able be able to get the code to work as XML and HTML, and view it in a browser. I am getting this error when I load the XML file into a browser:

Firefox

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>   Location: file:///C:/Users/fenwky/XmlDoc.xml
>   Line Number 2, Column 6:`<?xsl:stylesheet <abc:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">?>`

Chrome

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 2 at column 16: colon are forbidden from PI names 'xsl:transform'

This is what my c# code looks like in visual studio 2013:

```
// Create a procesing instruction.
XmlProcessingInstruction newPI;

// Stylesheet
String PItext = "<abc:stylesheet xmlns:abc=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">";
newPI = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("abc:stylesheet", PItext);
doc.InsertAfter(newPI, doc.FirstChild);

// Save document
doc.Save(xmlfilename);
```

Comment: The XML `<?xsl:stylesheet <abc:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">?>` is indeed invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to insert an processing instruction into the XML, the data parameter of the `CreateProcessingInstruction` method does not need to contain the name of the processing instruction in this case. In other words you just need to do this...

```
  var PItext = "xmlns:abc=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\"";
  var newPI = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("abc:stylesheet", PItext);
  doc.InsertAfter(newPI, doc.FirstChild);
```

However, I am wondering why you are trying to add this particular processing instruction to an XML document. Perhaps you mean to link an XML document to a separate XSLT document, so it will be transformed if read by a browser?

If so, you probably need to be doing this...

```
  var piText = "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"style1.xsl\"";
  var newPI = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", piText);
  doc.InsertAfter(newPI, doc.FirstChild);
```

This will write the following processing instruction to the XML, which can then be read by the browser:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style1.xsl"?>
```